# similar sphinxsearch geodistance sorting in elasticsearch

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch, sphinx

i have done aggregation with name but geo-distance sorting not working properly.
i have achieved to aggregation and distance calculation. but i don't know how to soring bucket distance value.
kindly suggest me how to achieved?

Mapping:-

```
PUT /museums
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data values:

```
POST /museums/doc/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"location": "52.374081,4.912350", "name": "NEMO Science Museum"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"location": "52.369219,4.901618", "name": "Museum Het Rembrandthuis"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"location": "52.371667,4.914722", "name": "Nederlands Scheepvaartmuseum"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"location": "51.222900,4.405200", "name": "Letterenhuis"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"location": "48.861111,2.336389", "name": "Musée du Louvre"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"location": "48.860000,2.327000", "name": "Musée d'Orsay"}
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{"location": "52.374081,4.912350", "name": "NEMO Science Museum"}
{"index":{"_id":8}}
{"location": "48.861111,2.336389", "name": "Musée du Louvre"}
```

Elastic Search query:

```
POST /museums/_search?size=0
{
        "query": {

        },
        "sort": {
            "_geo_distance": {
                "location": {
                        "lat": 52.3760,
                        "lon": 4.894
                },
                "order": "asc",
                "unit": "km",
                "distance_type": "arc"
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "by_id": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "name.keyword",
                    "order": {
                      "_count": "asc"
                    },
                    "size": 20
                },
                "aggregations":{
                  "top":{
                    "top_hits":
                    {
                      "sort":{
                        "_geo_distance":{
"location":{"lat":19.143172,"lon":72.824966
                          }
              }
    }
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

above query giving result but not sorting by distance.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misread you, but you are trying to fetch locations within X km/miles from another point?

If so, there is an equation called the Haversine formula, which uses spherical trigonometry to calculate areas within a certain distance! It looks like this:

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
Δlat = lat2− lat1
Δlong = long2− long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
Angles need to be in radians to pass to Trigonometric functions
```

Which is all very mathematical to me. In a MySQL query however, it looks like this:

```
SELECT *, 
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(55.864237) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-4.251806) ) + sin( radians(55.864237) ) 
 * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM postcodes HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

Here I check for any area within 20 miles, but you can make this as short or long as you want.  The 3959 figure at the start of the query is the number used for miles, if you are using kilometres you should change this number to 6371.  I have limited it to 1 row, as I only want the closest match, however you may want to change this in other situations!

Comment: my query giving distance but i m stuck only sorting.but manually we achieve this that time we featch all data after sorting.i don't know how to do in elasticsearch.

Comment: Ah ok, well clearly this isn't MySQL, so I guess I can't really be any more help!

Comment: sorry i couldn't be any more use :-P